# Does any programming language support the expressions like "12.Pounds.ToKilograms()"?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, units-of-measurement

Converting units and measurements from one system to another can be achieved in most programming languages in one or another way. But, Can we express something like "12.Pounds.ToKilograms()" in any programming language?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly in that syntax but you may want to take a look at Frink: https://frinklang.org

Frink syntax is similar to Google Calculator or Wolfram Alpha but not exactly the same. Whereas Google and Wolfram Alpha uses the `in` keyword to trigger unit conversion Frink uses the `->` operator. So in frink, the following is valid source code:

```
    // Calculate length of Wifi antenna:
    lightspeed / (2.4GHz) / 4 -> inches
```

As I mentioned, this syntax is similar to Google. For reference, the same calculation in Google syntax is `speed of light / 2.4GHz / 4 in inches`. Frink predates **both** Google calculator and Wolfram Alpha. I was first aware of frink sometime in the early 2000s.

Frink is unit aware. A number in frink always has unit even if that unit is simply "scalar" (no units). So to declare a variable that is 12 pounds you'd do:

```
var x = 12 pounds
```

To convert you'd do:

```
x -> kg
```

Or you can simply write the expression:

```
12 pounds -> kg
```

Answer (score 1):

In Smalltalk you could express this as

```
12 pounds inKilograms
```

Notice however that it is up to you to program both messages `pounds` and `inKilograms` (there are libraries that do that kind of things also). But the key point is that the expression above is perfectly valid in Smalltalk (even if these messages do not exist).

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've ever seen this as a valid expression. 12 would have to be defined as a type. Let's assume 12 is an integer. An integer type only knows that it is an integer and in most languages there are built in functions/ methods for integers. For this to be a valid expression you would need to define a weight type and within that object you could define methods of conversion or inherit child types with conversion methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in Ruby because of it's syntactic sugar.

Actually there's a ruby gem - [alchemist](https://github.com/halogenandtoast/alchemist) - you should check it out.
For example you could write:
`10.miles.to.meters`